# Fair use vs Photo of Convicted Criminal

Tags: fair-use

Imagine writing an article about a convicted criminal, only to discover that there are no photos of the individual that are in the public domain. You find a couple photos in magazines, but your requests for permission to use them go unanswered.

Would the fair use doctrine allow one to use such a photo without permission, or are there too many variables involved to make such a blanket assessment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Impossible to say, and highly dependent on the jurisdiction.

- Privacy laws may or may not apply to the publication of pictures, even for convicted criminals. There are jurisdictions where you cannot even use the full name amd a public domain photo from another context.
- The magazines have likely sourced the image from agencies or photographers, which means *they* cannot license you, and they may be too busy to answer requests from people who do not understand that much. (This might look different if the images are a couple of decades old. There were more staff reporters than there are today, in some parts of the world.)
- The presence or absence of **other** images of the same subject in the public domain should make absolutely no difference in this case. Either the photographer has a right to the picture, or not.

'Fair use' does not mean 'it is unfair that I cannot find a photo, so I'll use this one.'